# Calabash always logging Errno::ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, runtime-error, calabash

I am trying to run a calabash script on iOS but continually getting the following errors:

```
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    Given I am on the homepage # features/step_definitions/homepage_steps.rb:6
      Connection refused - connect(2) (http://localhost:37265) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
      ./features/PageObjects/home_page.rb:12:in `initialize'
      ./features/step_definitions/homepage_steps.rb:7:in `new'
      ./features/step_definitions/homepage_steps.rb:7:in `/^I am on the homepage$/'
      features/general.feature:9:in `Given I am on the homepage'
```

Anyone have any suggestions on fixing this error?

Comment: We need more information.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are running on iOS or Android.

Running on Android, this can be caused by the device disconnecting from USB (unstable USB connection), or becoming invisible to ADB in some other way.

Comment: Good point.  I have updated the question to mention iOS. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In this instance I fixed this by commenting ount 'APP_BUNDLE_PATH' within 01_launch.rb file.  All working now.

So looks like the path to the APP_BUNDLE_PATH was set incorrectly.  Hopefully this answer might help others.